# Find overlapping ranges between two int arrays and split/insert them

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

There two arrays, each of which will always contain an even, (*though not equal*) number of integers so that each pair will form a range, eg. 1..5, 8..12, etc.

```
var defaultArray: [Int] = [1, 5, 8, 12]
var priorityArray: [Int] = [1, 3, 5, 10, 13, 20]
```

What I'm looking for is a generic algorithm that will find each occurrence of where a range from **priorityArray** overlaps a range from **defaultArray** and will insert the **priorityRange** into the **defaultArray** while splitting the **defaultRange** apart if necessary.

The goal is to have a combined array of ranges while maintaining their original "types" like so:

```
var result: [Int] = [
    1, 3,   // priority
    3, 5,   // default
    5, 10,  // priority
    10, 12, // default
    13, 20  // priority
]
```

I'll use a simple struct to illustrate the final desired result:

```
var result: [Range] = [
   Range(from: 1, until: 3, key: "priority"),
   Range(from: 3, until: 5, key: "default"),
   Range(from: 5, until: 10, key: "priority"),
   Range(from: 10, until: 12, key: "default"),
   Range(from: 13, until: 20, key: "priority")
]
```

Comment: Can you give more examples that cover all possible cases? I see it is very straight forward.

Comment: There might also be a case where the priority range say 4..6 is between a default range of 2..10, so you would have to add 4, 4, 6, 6 for a total of [2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 10], but the key thing here is to know whether a given range is priority or default in a combined array.

Comment: Can the default ranges overlap each other? Can the priority ranges?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by overlapping with each other. The ranges are created by striding through an array by an increment of 2, so regardless of the integers themselves, as long as the arrays contain an even number of entries, there's a valid range. Or perhaps you'e asking whether the arrays will always be sorted in an ascending order?

Comment: For example would [1,10, 3,12] be valid default ranges? I was imagining by a range lo,hi you meant a set { x | lo<=x<hi} or the like, and then the first range in my example 1,10 overlaps the second [3,12]

Comment: Ah, I see your point now. In this case [1, 10, 3, 12] would be valid, so they are overlapping. The integers are timestamps in seconds in a 24h format representing time ranges within a given day which I'm mapping onto a Gantt chart. The tricky bit is that the prio ranges should override any def ranges that they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

We start with those arrays `def` and `prio` and first check if the intervals themselves are sorted wrt their start/end points. Those arrays would then contain the smallest number in the first array position. Ensure these arrays are simple/correct (=no overlapping intervals). If they are not, you can simplify/sanitise them.

We then initialise

- array index `d=0` to index the `def` array
- array index `p=0` to index the `prio` array
- a new array `result` to hold all your newly created intervals.
- a variable `s=none` to hold the current status

We now determine if the relation between the `def[d]` and `prio[p]`.
If `def[d]`<`prio[p]`, we set `t=def[d]`, increment `d` and set `s=def`.
If `def[d]`> `prio[p], we set` t=prio[p], increment `p` and set `s=prio`.
If they are equal, we set `t=prio[p]`, increment `p` and `d` and set `s=both`.

We can now initialise a new entry for the `result` array with start=`def[0]`. The priority is either `def` (if `s==def`) or `prio` (if `s` was `prio` or `both`). To determine the end, you can again compare def[d] with prio[p] to determine where it should end. At this point, you should adjust `s` again, but ensure that you keep track of the proper state which you're in (going from `both` to `def`, `prio` or `none` depending on the relation between `def[d]` and `prio[p]`). As mentioned in the comments of the OP, the different possibilities might require more clarification, but you should be able to incorporate them into a state.

Going from there, you can keep iterating and adjusting your variables until both are done (with `d=len(def)` and `p=len(prio)`. You should end up with a nice array containing all the desired consolidated intervals.

This is basically a stateful sweep through the 2 arrays, keeping track of the current position in the integer range and advancing 1 (maybe 2) position(s) at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm not sure I entirely understand your answer. Could you please clarify which array are you looping through when you're determining the relation between def[d] and prio[p]?

Comment: you actually iterate the def and prio arrays simultaneously. You start out with both d and p at 0. Depending on the relation between def[0] and prio[0], you perform the appropriate action (see above) including updating s and the result array as well as  incrementing d or p (or both).